# Activate an authorized Google Sheets add-on in a new document without "Use in this doc" menu process

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization, google-apps-script-addon

I wanted to create an Google Sheets Add-on that opens a sidebar.

In the spreadsheet in which I've coded my Google Script, everything goes well. I published it on the market (for private user) and installed on tester's accounts.

On set-up, everything goes well but when we try to use it on another sheet, the item in my add-on menu doesn't show up. We have to go to *Addons -> Manage Addons -> "my addon" -> Use in this doc*

We've looked deeper and see that the `Auth.Mode` didn't authorize my add-on to be used directly when we open/create the spreadsheet.

I would like to know how to, once a user installs the add-on, have every spreadsheet of this user utilize the add-on directly, without the necessity of going through the menus to activate "use in this doc".

Here's an image showing the desired and current behavior:
[image: See my problem in image]

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't provide an "Always use this add-on" option - the user has to choose to use your add-on in each spreadsheet that they want to use it. If they don't want to use your add-on, you can't force them to.

Consider this from a security perspective - malicious add-ons would always ask to be used in every user document. The current model ensures that an add-on is only used when wanted, severely hampering malicious data collection / privacy violation.

[Instructions for using add-ons and Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

If you're in GSuite, things can be a bit different. I don't have access to a GSuite environment so I can't speak to the particulars, but I would imagine your domain administrator can install add-ons as they see fit. I can see the use case for DAs to also be able to activate their add-ons automatically, to provide tailored services to their organization. Add-ons from the marketplace are still likely to operate with the opt-in-only security model.